# Map Toolbar issue in map v2 Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I am developing an Android project with a map displaying my current location and many markers on a map version2. My problem is that I cannot display Map Toolbar icon for map directions on my map with:

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
```

Instead, I can set Compass, ZoomControls,MyLocationButton.
I see that in UiSetting.class there is no method: isMapToolbarEnabled() & setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean enabled). Is this related to build.gradle file?

```
compileSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion : 21,
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
```

How can I fix UiSettings.class and enable Map Toolbar on my map?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by updating
from

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

Now map toolbar is shown each time I click on a marker.